# What is the purpose of the org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run() function in Hadoop?

Tags: function, dictionary, hadoop

What is the purpose of the `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run()` function in Hadoop? The `setup()` is called before calling the `map()` and the `clean()` is called after the `map()`. The documentation for the `run()` says

> Expert users can override this method for more complete control over the execution of the Mapper.

I am looking for the practical purpose of this function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The default `run()` method simply takes each key / value pair supplied by the context and calls the `map()` method:

```
public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    setup(context);
    while (context.nextKeyValue()) {
       map(context.getCurrentKey(), context.getCurrentValue(), context);
    }
    cleanup(context);
}
```

If you wanted to do more than that ... you'd need to override it. For example, the [MultithreadedMapper](http://search-hadoop.com/c/Map/Reduce:/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/map/MultithreadedMapper.java) class

Comment: @Brain - still not clear - when it is called by the MR framework and what's the purpose of it. If I comment out the call to the run() in the MR framework, I don't think there would any change in the o/p of my MR program.

Comment: @praveen - if you commented out the `run()` in the `Mapper` class ... it wouldn't *do* anything. It's what calls your `map()` method for each key/value pair. The MR framework creates a `Mapper` for each `InputSplit` and calls the `run()` method.

Comment: @Brain - So the MR framework actually calls the run() which will the call the setup(), map() n times and finally cleanup(). Guess there would be something similar Reduce.run() also.

Answer (score 1):

I just came up with a fairly odd case for using this.

Occasionally I've found that I want a mapper that consumes all its input before producing any output. I've done it in the past by performing the record writes in my cleanup function. My map function doesn't actually output any records, it just reads the input and stores whatever will be needed in private structures.

It turns out that this approach works fine unless you're producing a LOT of output. The best I can make out is that the mapper's spill facility doesn't operate during cleanup. So the records that are produced just keep accumulating in memory, and if there are too many of them you risk heap exhaustion. This is my speculation of what's going on - could be wrong. But definitely the problem goes away with my new approach.

That new approach is to override run() instead of cleanup(). My only change to the default run() is that after the last record has been delivered to map(), I call map() once more with null key and value. That's a signal to my map() function to go ahead and produce its output. In this case, with the spill facility still operable, memory usage stays in check.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it could be used for debugging purposes as well. You can then skip part of the input key-value pairs (=take a sample) to test your code.